# Excel - I need the ROW formula to go down, when I drag across

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the formula below, which I would like to drag horizontally but have the **ROW(1:1)** change vertically, e.g. become **ROW(2:2)**, etc.:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($B$1:$C$800,SMALL(IF($C$1:$C$800=S$2,ROW($C$1:$C$800)),ROW(1:1)),1)),"",INDEX($B$1:$C$800,SMALL(IF($C$1:$C$800=S$2,ROW($C$1:$C$800)),ROW(1:1)),1))
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

What you’re asking for is impossible. 
But you’re asking for the wrong thing. 
If you want a term in a formula to increase as you drag it to the right,
use `COLUMN(A:A)`
(or `COLUMN(An)`, where *`n`* is any valid row number).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your actual question, the best you can do is replace `1:1` with `OFFSET(1:1,COLUMN()+0,)`. The `1:1` won't actually change, but the result will be the same as if it did.

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($B$1:$C$800,SMALL(IF($C$1:$C$800=S$2,ROW($C$1:$C$800)),ROW(OFFSET(1:1,COLUMN()+0,))),1)),"",INDEX($B$1:$C$800,SMALL(IF($C$1:$C$800=S$2,ROW($C$1:$C$800)),ROW(OFFSET(1:1,COLUMN()+0,))),1))
```

Depending on how you're using the formula, a better solution is to replace `ROW(1:1)` with `COLUMN()`:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($B$1:$C$800,SMALL(IF($C$1:$C$800=S$2,ROW($C$1:$C$800)),COLUMN()),1)),"",INDEX($B$1:$C$800,SMALL(IF($C$1:$C$800=S$2,ROW($C$1:$C$800)),COLUMN()),1))
```